# Regular expression/Regex with Java/Javascript: performance drop or infinite loop

Tags: regex, performance

I want here to submit a very specific performance problem that i want to understand.

#### Goal

I'm trying to validate a custom synthax with a regex. Usually, i'm not encountering performance issues, so i like to use it.

#### Case

The regex:

```
^(\{[^\][{}(),]+\}\s*(\[\s*(\[([^\][{}(),]+\s*(\(\s*([^\][{}(),]+\,?\s*)+\))?\,?\s*)+\]\s*){1,2}\]\s*)*)+$
```

A valid synthax:

```
{Section}[[actor1, actor2(syno1, syno2)][expr1,expr2]][[actor3,actor4(syno3, syno4)][expr3,expr4]]
```

You could find the regex and a test text here :
https://regexr.com/3jama

I hope that be sufficient enough, i don't know how to explain what i want to match more than with a regex ;-).

#### Issue

Applying the regex on valid text is not costing much, it's almost instant.
But when it comes to specific not valid text case, the regexr app hangs. It's not specific to regexr app since i also encountered dramatic performances with my own java code or javascript code.

Thus, my needs is to validate all along the user is typing the text. I can even imagine validating the text on click, but i cannot afford that the app will be hanging if the text submited by the user is structured as the case below, or another that produce the same performance drop.

#### Reproducing the issue

Just remove the trailing "]" character from the test text

So the invalid text to raise the performance drop becomes:

```
{Section}[[actor1, actor2(syno1, syno2)][expr1,expr2]][[actor3,actor4(syno3, syno4)][expr3,expr4
```

Another invalid test could be, and with no permformance drop:

```
{Section}[[actor1, actor2(syno1, syno2)][expr1,expr2]][[actor3,actor4(syno3, syno4)][expr3,expr4]]]
```

#### Request

I'll be glad if a regex guru coming by could explain me what i'm doing wrong, or why my use case isn't adapted for regex.

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve] **here**. Not in a link

Comment: `[\s\t\n\r]*` is completely useless - `\s*` does the same and is more readable. Additionally, the syntax for the square brackets could be `[^][{}(),]+` (no need to escape everything).

Comment: a little explaination of the regex would still be welcome, it is maybe a bit overcomplexified; you could replace all the `[\s\t\n\r]*` by `\s*` for example

Comment: @Suraj Rao : i edited my post

Comment: @Jan @Kaddath : i applied your suggestion, i wasn't not aware that `\s` class contains all

Comment: @Vadim Kotov it's seems that i overrided your edit, thanks though

Comment: Guys, put me in the right way, i'm not uderstanding why this is off topic, what cannot be reproduce ? I state that is a performance problem, and i tell to remove the trailing character from the correct synthax to encounter the performance drop, the regexr link is straight to reproduce it. Really, explain me, please

Comment: @Jan there's a small mistake in your second advice, `]` at least should be escaped, or else the char list ends there, which becomes `[^\][{}(),]+`

Comment: @Kaddath i edited my post accordingly, and i thank you all to point me out how it could be more readable and minimal, but the performances are still the same. Does anyone tried to remove the trailing character and sees the performance issue ?

Comment: @rtribotte in the case of a failed match, backtracking starts to kick off. Then constructs like `[^\][{}(),]+\,?\s*` where characters can be occopied by the character class as well as the `\s` open the gates to catastrophic backtracking, especially if they appear in repeated groups with no other boundaries around.

Comment: In many engines you can use atomic grouping and/or possessive quantifiers to work around such issues, or you always use clear boundaries (in the case shown e.g. `[^\][{}(),]+(?:,\s*)?`)

Comment: @Jan OP mentions JavaScript in the title - in that case you have to escape it. `[^]` is valid in JS regex.

Comment: yes that would have surprised me, as i actually tested it before commenting

Comment: @Sebastian Proske Thanks for your constructive comments, i tried to put off the ability to have multilining and spaces between reserved character (`()[]{}`), so the expected synthax must be a one line expression whithout spaces, thus, the performance drop is still there, the regex is now : `^(\{[^\][{}(),]+\}(\[(\[([^\][{}(),]+(\(([^\][{}(),]+\,?)+\)‌​)?\,?)+\]){1,2}\])*)‌​+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for the condensed regex from your comment:

```
^(\{[^\][{}(),]+\}(\[(\[([^\][{}(),]+(\(([^\][{}(),]+\,?)+\))?\,?)+\]){1,2}\])*)+$
```

The issues are similar for your original pattern.

You are facing catastrophic backtracking. Whenever the regex engine cannot complete a match, it backtracks into the string, trying to find other ways to match the pattern to certain substrings. If you have lots of ambiguous patterns, especially if they occur inside repetitions, testing all possible variations takes a looooong time. See [link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for a better explanation.

One of the subpatterns that you use is the following (multilined for better visualisation):

```
([^\][{}(),]+
  (\(
    ([^\][{}(),]+\,?)+
  \))?
\,?)+
```

That is supposed to match a string like `actor4(syno3, syno4)`. Condensing this pattern a little more, you get to `([^\][{}(),]+,?)+`. If you remove the `,?` from it, you get `([^\][{}(),]+)+` which is an opening gate to the catasrophic backtracking, as string can be matched in quite a lot of different ways with this pattern.

I get what you try to do with this pattern - match an identifier - and maybe other other identifiers that are separated by comma. The proper way of doing this however is: `([^\][{}(),]+(?:,[^\][{}(),]+)*)`. Now there isn't an ambiguous way left to backtrack into this pattern.

Doing this for the whole pattern shown above (yes, there is another optional comma that has to be rolled out) and inserting it back to your complete pattern I get to:

```
^(\{[^\][{}(),]+\}(\[(\[([^\][{}(),]+(\(([^\][{}(),]+(?:,[^\][{}(),]+)*)\))?(?:\,[^\][{}(),]+(\(([^\][{}(),]+(?:,[^\][{}(),]+))*\))?)*)\]){1,2}\])*)+$
```

Which doesn't catastrophically backtrack [anymore](https://regex101.com/r/IHlERF/1/).

You might want to do yourself a favour and split this into subpatterns that you concat together either using strings in your actual source or using defines if you are using a PCRE pattern.

Note that some regex engines allow the use of atomic groups and possessive quantifiers that further help avoiding needless backtracking. As you have used different languages in your title, you will have to check yourself, which one is available for your language of choice.

Comment: First, i want to thank you for your time, it took half an hour until i catch the trick for my case, you've explained it very well, and regular-expressions.info dedicated page as well. I have to go further to understand the use of atomic groups and possessive quantifiers, and see what i could do in java. Many thanks, you put me in the right way, to not say that you did the job for me, and you put a word on the symptoms :  Catastrophic Backtracking